# How to solve Medication posession ratio (MPR) problem?

Tags: clojure

I am trying to solve medication possession ration problem.

I tried using intervals and then comparing them with observation period.

```
(ns clara-rules.mpr-new
  (:require [clj-time.core :as t]
            [clj-time.format :as f]))

(defn observe [interval]
  (def start (map #(f/parse (f/formatter "dd MM yyyy") (% :start_)) interval))
  (def end (map #(f/parse (f/formatter "dd MM yyyy") (% :end_)) interval))

  )
(observe '({:start_ "20 01 2012" :end_ "20 02 2012"}
           {:start_ "20 02 2012" :end_ "20 03 2012"}
           {:start_ "20 04 2012" :end_ "20 05 2012"}
           {:start_ "20 06 2012" :end_ "20 07 2012"}))


(defn calc[a b]
(def start_date (f/parse (f/formatter "dd MM yyyy") a)
  )

  (def end_date (f/parse (f/formatter "dd MM yyyy")b)
      )

  (def observation_period(t/in-days(t/interval start_date end_date)))
  (println observation_period)
  )
(calc "01 02 2012" "01 12 2012")

(defn mpr_ratio[]

  (def overlp (map #(t/overlap (t/interval start_date end_date) (t/interval %1 %2))start end))

  (def x (map #(t/in-days %)overlp))
  (println x)
  (def ratio (reduce +(map #(float(*(/ % observation_period)100))x)))
  (println ratio)
  )
(mpr_ratio)
```

I expect the calculated ratio of all the intervals and the observation period.

Comment: Never use `def` inside `defn` - use `let` instead.

Comment: new to clojure,will keep that in mind but will that solve my problem?

Comment: there are just too many syntax errors here. To name a few: `def`, lambda without params, `map` with value instead of function, `map` without mapped collection (which is good, if you use a transducer, bot not here).. Try to read some clojure syntax introduction, since you can't distinguish wrong logic from wrong syntax now.

Comment: i corrected my syntax and my program works now,the only problem is that ,when i change the start date of observation period,it gives me error

Comment: could you update your question with new attempt?

Comment: i have updated the code but if (calc "01 02 2012" "01 12 2012") to (calc "01 03 2012" "01 12 2012") it gives me error. I expect start of interval to be taken just as the  observation period startdate,same for the observation end date and end of the intervals.

Comment: in other words (observe '({:start_ "20 01 2012" :end_ "20 02 2012"}
           {:start_ "20 02 2012" :end_ "20 03 2012"}
           {:start_ "20 04 2012" :end_ "20 05 2012"}
           {:start_ "20 06 2012" :end_ "20 07 2012"})),,,start of this list is before observation period which cannot happen,it should be able to start automatically from observation period start date

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. This question feels like it is iterating on getting your whole code working, which isn’t the intent of this site. Consider reworking it to a specific question (how do I get the number of days between two date strings?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few suggestions:

1. Use function with return value instead of relying on side effect (`println` and `def` inside a function) to obtain your result
2. Use `def` only for top level var, use `let` for any temporary var
   inside a function
3. Create some single purpose functions (e.g. function to parse date; function to convert list of observations to dates), then use those functions to compose your solution
4. Use thread macro (e.g. `->` `->>`) to improve readability

Possible solution:

```clj
(def fmt
  "default date formatter"
  (f/formatter "dd MM yyyy"))

(def ->date
  "utility function to convert string to date"
  (partial f/parse fmt))

(->date "01 02 2012")
;; => #object[org.joda.time.DateTime 0x6e880ccd "2012-02-01T00:00:00.000Z"]

(defn ->observations
  [intervals]
  (->> intervals
       (map (fn [{:keys [start_ end_]}]
              {:start (->date start_)
               :end   (->date end_)}))))

(->observations '({:start_ "20 01 2012" :end_ "20 02 2012"}
                  {:start_ "20 02 2012" :end_ "20 03 2012"}))
;; => ({:start #object[org.joda.time.DateTime 0x4eb450bd "2012-01-20T00:00:00.000Z"], :end #object[org.joda.time.DateTime 0x558bd20f "2012-02-20T00:00:00.000Z"]} {:start #object[org.joda.time.DateTime 0x4009d145 "2012-02-20T00:00:00.000Z"], :end #object[org.joda.time.DateTime 0x42e32d6 "2012-03-20T00:00:00.000Z"]})

(defn mpr_ratio
  [start_date end_date intervals]
  (let [intrvrl   (t/interval start_date end_date)
        obsrv-prd (t/in-days intrvrl)]
    (->> (map t/interval (map :start intervals) (map :end intervals))
         (map (partial t/overlap intrvrl))
         (map t/in-days)
         (map #(-> %
                   (/ obsrv-prd)
                   (* 100.0)))
         (reduce +))))

(mpr_ratio (->date "01 02 2012")
           (->date "01 12 2012")
           (->observations '({:start_ "20 01 2012" :end_ "20 02 2012"}
                             {:start_ "20 02 2012" :end_ "20 03 2012"}
                             {:start_ "20 04 2012" :end_ "20 05 2012"}
                             {:start_ "20 06 2012" :end_ "20 07 2012"})))
;; => 35.526315789473685
```

**UPDATE - PDC utility function**

```
(defn covered [state interval]
  (if (some #(t/overlaps? interval %) state)
    (->> state
         (map #(if (t/overlaps? interval %)
                 (t/interval (t/min-date (t/start %) (t/start interval))
                             (t/max-date (t/end %) (t/end interval)))
                 %))
         (into (empty state)))
    (conj state interval)))

(covered #{} (t/interval (->date "01 02 2012") (->date "05 02 2012")))
;; => #{#object[org.joda.time.Interval 0x30addc0b "2012-02-01T00:00:00.000Z/2012-02-05T00:00:00.000Z"]}
(covered *1 (t/interval (->date "04 02 2012") (->date "07 02 2012")))
;; => #{#object[org.joda.time.Interval 0x7f8893c1 "2012-02-01T00:00:00.000Z/2012-02-07T00:00:00.000Z"]}
(covered *1 (t/interval (->date "02 03 2012") (->date "07 03 2012")))
;; => #{#object[org.joda.time.Interval 0x7f8893c1 "2012-02-01T00:00:00.000Z/2012-02-07T00:00:00.000Z"] #object[org.joda.time.Interval 0x67adc8d1 "2012-03-02T00:00:00.000Z/2012-03-07T00:00:00.000Z"]}
(reduce + (map (comp inc t/in-days) *1))
;; => 13
```

pdc function in full:  (note that only one line needs to be added)

```
(defn pdc_ratio
  [start_date end_date intervals]
  (let [intrvrl   (t/interval start_date end_date)
        obsrv-prd (t/in-days intrvrl)]
    (->> (map t/interval (map :start intervals) (map :end intervals))
         (map (partial t/overlap intrvrl))
         ;; get covered days only
         (reduce covered #{})
         (map t/in-days)
         (map #(-> %
                   (/ obsrv-prd)
                   (* 100.0)))
         (reduce +))))
```

Comment: Could u do me one more favour and tell me how can i solve the PDC problem,if you are familiar with that problem

Comment: It should really be a question on how to do union of interval.  Anyway I added a helper function for your reference.

Comment: what is the function of #{} and *1

Comment: `#{}` is an empty set, `*1` is the last evaluated result in the repl.  Anyway, I've added the pdc function in full. But I will suggest you to take some introductory tutorial on Clojure, something like https://github.com/functional-koans/clojure-koans

Answer (score 2):

that's how the day intervals function could look like:

```
(defn process []
  (let [from ["20 01 2012"
              "20 03 2012"
              "20 06 2012"
              "20 08 2012"]
        to ["20 02 2012"
            "20 05 2012"
            "20 07 2012"
            "20 09 2012"]
        get-date (partial f/parse (f/formatter "dd MM yyyy"))
        days (map #(t/in-days (t/interval (get-date %1) (get-date %2)))
                  from to)]
    days))

user> (process)
;;=> (31 61 30 31)
```

still, i advice you read some introduction to clojure